# Why does the 'qweb' report come out without data in odoo?

Tags: python, report, odoo, qweb

## I'm making a custom report but when printing it, everything goes blank without data or header or anything.

```
<template id="report_isrl_document">
    <t t-call="web.external_layout">
        <div class="page">
            <div class="row">
                <h3>Title</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </t>
</template>

<template id="report_isrl_main">
    <t t-call="web.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
            <t t-set="lang" t-value="o.user_id.lang if o.type in ('in_invoice', 'in_refund') else o.partner_id.lang"/>
            <t t-call="l10n_ve_isrl.report_isrl_document" t-lang="lang"/>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>

<record model="report.paperformat" id="paperformat_isrl_report">
    <field name="name">paperformat.isrl.report</field>
    <field name="default" eval="True"/>
    <field name="format">Letter</field>
    <field name="page_width">0</field>
    <field name="page_width">0</field>
    <field name="orientation">Landscape</field>
    <field name="margin_top">30</field>
    <field name="margin_right">5</field>
    <field name="margin_bottom">10</field>
    <field name="margin_left">5</field>
    <field name="header_line" eval="False"/>
    <field name="header_spacing">20</field>
    <field name="dpi">90</field>
</record>

<report
    string="ISRL Report"
    id="action_report_isrl"
    model="account.invoice"
    report_type="qweb-pdf"
    name="l10n_ve_isrl.report_isrl_main"
    file="l10n_ve_isrl.report_isrl_main"
    print_report_name="'ISRL Report New"
    paperformat="paperformat_isrl_report"
    menu="False"
/>
```

## the call to the report I do it in the following way:

```
@api.multi
def get_isrl_report(self):

    data = {
        'ids': self.ids,
        'model': self._name,
        }

    return self.env.ref('l10n_ve_isrl.action_report_isrl').report_action(self, data=data)
```

## what is expected is that the page and footer appear and the word title in the report printed in pdf, what I get in an empty pdf

Comment: When creating a report from button click pass values for docs from a parser.

Comment: use this code "<t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">" only if you have to create multiple reports in a single click, else just create a normal report